# Cannot read property 'compilation' of undefined when running NPM script

Tags: shell, npm, elm

Recently we have been tasked to move from YARN to NPM in a project that was developed a few years ago.  The conversion was pretty smooth.  We have noticed the following error when trying to run this script:

```
 "start-frontend": "cd frontend && elm-app start",
```

The following error is returned when 'npm run start-frontend' is executed:

> digital_bill@1.0.0 start-frontend /Users/xxxx/workspace/kittyworks-frontend
> cd frontend && elm-app start

Failed to compile.

Cannot read property 'compilation' of undefined

There is a frontend directory as a child directory to where NPM is being run (location of package.json).  If I execute these commands in terminal the command 'elm-app start' works without error once we cd into frontend.

This is running on a MAC (Catalina) with NPM 6.1.8.  ELM is 0.18.

Not sure what is happening here.

Comment: Does it give you any clues as to where the error comes from? My gut is saying this is an issue with your build setup but without more details about how your build is setup it's hard to say.

Comment: Yeah I believe it is build specific.  We actually upgraded to 0.19 and the issue went away.   Probably some some of build dependency.   I find sometimes the errors come from dependencies of other items that maybe are installed and there is conflict of sorts.